# C++ and CMake: configure a template class from file

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a C++ 'library' which consists of a set of reusable classes which are templated (i.e. all source code is in header files) and a set of driver files. Each driver source file includes some (but not necessarily all) headers with class templates.

It would be nice if I could instantiate these class templates in each driver file with specific template parameters (known at compile time) and then automate the initialization of objects with the instantiated type by reading configuration files (this would help me remove some boilerplate code). These configuration files would be read upon object construction.

Suppose the config files would be bundled with the source code. Where should they be placed when drivers are compiled so that each class can locate its config files? I am using CMake to build the code.

Since reusable code is not compiled into a library, I can't place the config files in the same location as the library. I'm not even sure whether that would be a good idea actually.

One solution would be to specify a folder with config files as a CMake variable and hardcode this value in the source code of every configurable class. Is there a better way of doing this? Perhaps there's a standard CMake-style way of handling the problem?

Comment: I'm having some problems understanding this question. Are you talking about run-time configuration files? I.e. some kind of XML or JSON that you're feeding to an appropriate parser? Also, you seem to have an unusual vocabulary, at least if you're talking about real C++ ` template`s. If all source code is in header files, then why is there a CMake process involved? And what " driver source files" are needed? This might be an XY problem, but I can't even say that for certain.

Comment: @MSalters: Hi, yes I'm talking about run-time configuration. Not all source code is in headers, because each driver file contains its own main() and links other shared libraries which were obtained by compiling non-template code. It just so happens that most of the classes that I'd like to configure at run-time are also template classes (obviously the configuration parameters are not related to the template parameters).
What is so unusual about my vocabulary?

Comment: Well, I assume the headers really contain "class templates" not "template classes". In normal terminology, those templates are _instantiated_. You also mention "setup". This might or might not be _initialization_, but that applies to _objects_ - and template class instantiations are types, not objects. And since you are talking apparently about run-time configuration, the location of config files is typically an OS thing (and Windows uses the Registry instead), which you don't even mention.

Comment: I edited the question. I hope the phrasing is clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

I would  consider doing this with good 'ol macros. You can use `target_compile_definitions()` to define macros in your source code. Your config files could then be CMake files themselves, loaded with `include()`. Then in your source files, you could do an explicit template specialization or a typedef to `MyTemplateClass<TEMPLATE_ARG_MACRO_1, TEMPLATE_ARG_MACRO_2>`.

Hopefully that makes some sense.